# Using CNN for pixel classification,how?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pixel, pytorch

I have already learn about some classification using CNN like for Mnist. But recently I received a dataset which is consist of a vector set. The normal image dataset(mnist) is like nxcxwxh. The one I received is (w*h)x1xc. The goal is to train a network to classify these pixels(as I understand,is classification for pixels). The label length is groundtruth picture.

I am a little confused about this work. As I understand, for Image processing, we use the CNN with different receiption feld to make the convolution operations so that a feature can be obtained to represent the image. But in this case, the image is already expand to pixel-set. Why is the convolutional neural network still suitable?

Still I am not sure about the work but I started to try.I used the 1d convolution instead of 2d in the network. After 4-Conv1d,the output is connected to a softmax layer then fed to crossentropy loss function. It seems, I have some problems with the output dimensions so the network is not able to train.

I use pytorch to implement the work. Below is the network form I try to build. The dimensions do not match those need for crossentropyloss function. 122500 was set to be the sample numbers. So I think the convolution was performed along the 1-200 directions.

First I want to know,is that right to implement like this using conv1d when I want to classify the pixels?

If this thought was right, how can I continue to feed the features to the loss function?

If this is wrong,can I have some similar examples for this kind of work? I am new to python, so if there were some stupid mistakes, pls point out.

Thanks all.

```
class network(nn.Module):
"""
    Building network

"""
def __init__(self):
    super(network, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 1,out_channels = 32,stride = 1,kernel_size = 3)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 32,out_channels = 64,stride = 1,kernel_size = 3)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 64,out_channels = 128,stride = 1,kernel_size = 3)
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 128,out_channels = 256,stride = 1,kernel_size = 3)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(13, 2)

def forward(self,s):
    s = self.conv1(s)
    s = F.relu(F.max_pool1d(s, 2)) 
    s = self.conv2(s)
    s = F.relu(F.max_pool1d(s, 2)) 
    s = self.conv3(s)
    s = F.relu(F.max_pool1d(s, 2)) 
    s = self.conv4(s)
    s = F.relu(F.max_pool1d(s, 2)) 

    s = self.fc(s)

    s = F.softmax(s,1)


output = model(input)
loss = loss_fn(output, labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're supposed to do is [image segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) and in the shape of the labels you got, the last dimension of 200 corresponds to 200 possible categories of pixels (that sounds like a lot to me, but without more context I cannot judge). The problem of image segmentation is *way* too broad to explain in an SO answer, but I suggest you check resources such as [this tutorial](https://tuatini.me/practical-image-segmentation-with-unet/) and check out the [influential](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) [papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) in this field.

Comment: actually the pixels have only 2 possible categories, I do want to implement image segmentation later. but now the job is train a network to automaticlly reconignize the which category the pixel belongs to. The Image size was 350x350 but extended to 122500. Am I right to use 1d convolution? 200 is the depth(channel) of the Image(like the 3 in a normal RGB Image).@Jatentaki

Comment: If 200 is the number of channels - ok. What you mean by "350x350 extended to 122500"? 350*350 = 122500, so to me it sounds that you were given 2d data, which just happened to be unformatted (so you would reshape it to 350x350 anyway). I doubt 1d conv is the way to go. What do you mean by "category the pixel belongs to"? Are you categorizing a single pixel (*the* pixel) or all pixels in the image? Either way, I suggest you check with the person who gave you this assignment - you need to understand the format of input and output to do anything reasonable and SO cannot help you in that regard.

Comment: ok,thanks anyway. I asked the one who give me the data several times. As I only worked on the normal data with WxHxC before. I really doubt why he reshape the data from 350x350 to 122500(and I dont know how,so unable to get it back). From the last meeting with him, the job is to classify single pixel in the image.@Jatentaki